# avoid posting twice? gridview control

Tags: asp.net, gridview

in the gridview control when user edit the row and click on update button to save and then click on refresh button (IE) it execut the update event again.

how should i avoid if the user click on refresh after it updates the row?

Comment: Please add some details and code. It's hard to tell whats wrong if we can't see how events are handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can workaround this problem by using [Viewstate to store information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (MSDN Link).

After a user updates a row, in code-behind, save the fact that the row has been update.

```
ViewState["DataAlreadySaved"] = true;
```

In your Update method, put a check for the ViewState value to see if data has been saved.

```
If ((bool)ViewState["DataAlreadySaved"] == false) {
   //Save the data
} 
else {
   //Do nothing
}
```

You'll need to figure out the best way to handle things based on your code but this should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Are you handling the update in code-behind?  If so, you could perform a POST-Redirect-GET by redirecting to the current page.  Something like:

```
response.Redirect(request.Url.ToString());
```

When the user hits refresh, it will then just reload the page.